# RAID 5 with NVMe / Optane cache on a Z170?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, cache, nvme, optane

Information on this is sparse and i can't get clear answers so here goes:
I'm currently using a Z77 board and I'm looking into adding a Z170-/Z270-system and setting up a software-RAID 5-array with an NVMe-cache to offset the write penalty. Please refrain from "educating" me on the downsides and risks of RAID 5, I'm not interested in discussing that. My question is, can any NVMe be used as a cache or does it have to be Intel Optane? The Z170 chipset doesn't even support Optane as per Intel, the Z270 does but I'm not really keen on buying Intels overpriced proprietary nonsense, I'd much rather get a decent Samsung M.2 for half the price..

So does anyone have concrete information on this? Again, my goal is to supplement a RAID 5-array, but anyone who is running a Z170 or Z270 board with some kind of NVMe cache would be welcome to share their info and experience.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: For now, I need to work with Windows 7 and I would prefer using Intel RST or another low-cost option.

Comment: Optane Memory requires Intel RST, sincere Optane (cache) is only supported by specific Intel M.2 devices, you won’t be able to use Samsung with Intel RST, there might be third-party software that will let you use Samsung hardware but it won’t be with Intel RST.

Comment: @Ramhound - urgh. Let me guess, it still requires a minimum of 18.6 GB for the cache? Also, if I stick to SATA SSD for the cache, can I then use another brand or does Intel exclude all other brands past 1150 chipsets? I'm guessing it's a driver thing anyway, but old 1150-era drivers probably won't work on a 1151 board? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I am only familiar with Optane, determined it wasn’t worth it, when purchasing what’s an already extremely fast SSD. Making an SSD into a cache drive doesn’t require Optane, Optane, is just Intel’s method.

Answer (score 0):

Any drive can be used as cache. Even a fast HDD (though that does not make much sense unless you have a very fast HDD and extremely slow main storage).

TEchnically the answer thus is: Yes, you can use the Samsung drive as cache.

But, it all depends on the software/drivers.

Since you mention Intel Optane, I am assuming a windows setup with RST. And in that part I lack experience.   Now if you asked ZFS (probably on a BSD or on Solaris) then the answer would be a much harder "Yes".

Comment: Yes, RST in Windows preferably, since it's more or less "inbuilt" with Intel mainboards and offers decent performance, once you set it up. I know there are paid tools for Windows that exist, but I would like to avoid buying extra software. I know Linux might be an easier option, but since I want to use the RAID array inside my Windows work environment, that alternative includes extra challenges/hurdles.